# Regarding the sorted test plan in alphabetical order in azure devops

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, automation-testing

I have a automation test project in azure devops in which I have created a test plan. The test displays clients for which the tests are performed. The tests are displayed according to the time of their execution. My query is whether I can sort the client list by their names i.e. in alphabetical order.

Comment: Do you want to sort the client list in the test plan, or in the display of test results in Azure DevOps? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to sort the client list alphabetical order in both "test plan and test result in Azure DevOps".